# Change sequelize timezone

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I want to make restful app in nodejs

Server: centos 7 64x
Database: postgresql
Additional: express, sequelize
Table: datetime with timezone

When I selecting rows with sequelize from database, created_at column gives me wrong time. 5 hour added to datetime.

I change timezone configuration of centos to +5 (Tashkent/Asia)
Also change postgresql timezone configuration to +5
Datetime is correct in database when shows.

But when I select it converts to like this

"createdAt": "2018-08-12T17:57:20.508Z"

In database column shows this

2018-08-12 22:57:20.508+05

config.json

```
"development": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "zablet",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "timezone": "Tashkent/Ashgabat",
    "define": {
        "charset": "utf8",
        "dialectOptions": {
            "collate": "utf8_general_ci"
        },
        "freezeTableName": true
    }
}
```

index.js

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename = path.basename(__filename);
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config = require('../config/config.json')[env];
var db = {};
if (config.use_env_variable) {
    var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
    var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}
fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
    })
    .forEach(file => {
        var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });
Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
module.exports = db;
```

updated config.json

```
{
    "development": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "postgres",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "define": {
        "charset": "utf8",
        "dialectOptions": {
            "collate": "utf8_general_ci"
        },
        "freezeTableName": true
    },
    "dialectOptions": {
        "useUTC": false
    },
    "timezone": "+05:00"
}
}
```

How can I select rows from database in correct timezone format?

Comment: If you are building REST API, you better store dates in UTC in the database and then do a conversion in the client. Why? Imagine that your API has users from different timezones... that's it, your API just got inadequate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its because you are setting timezone only for writing to the database, not for reading. This works correctly. I am using this.

```
development: {
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'postgres',
    database: 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
      useUTC: false, // for reading from database
    },
    timezone: '+05:30', // for writing to database
  },
```

---

If still it does not work then add the following attribute into the sequelize constructor in the connection.js.

```
dialectOptions:{useUTC:false},timezone:"+05:30"
```

Similar to the below code:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize("DB",'USER','PWD',{host:'127.0.0.1',dialect:"mysql",operatorsAliases:0,timezone:"+05:30"})
```

Comment: What you are seeing I am using this one. and it works fine for me

Comment: you wan't see saved data in required timzezone. to do that you have to set timezone at database options. 
If you will query after above configuration it  always return results corrospondin to your timezone query.

Comment: Nope. Maybe I left something another configuration?

Comment: can you define dialectOption like which i defined

Comment: I put it below define in updated question. Maybe problem in postgresql?

Comment: @RahulSharma, If I save with time zone GMT-8 for example, shouldn't I see a different time in my phpmyadmin db ?

Answer (score 2):

Use in Config JSON

```
"production": {
    "username": "xyz",
    "password": "",
    "database": "dbname",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "port": 123,
    "dialectOptions": {
      "useUTC": false 
    },
    "timezone": "+05:30"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.