# how to resolve time difference of 8 hours mariadb and nodejs on same linux server

Tags: node.js, linux, mariadb

Would like advise on why there is time difference of 8 hours and how to resolve it? Thanks

The actual date and time of execution is **2019-08-16 10:37:41**

**MariaDB table pure insert
SQL statement :**

```
INSERT INTO ib_system_log (login, ACTION, action_type) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test');
```

**Result :**

```
| login | action |  create_date_time   | action_type |      
| test  | test   | 2019-08-16 10:37:41 | test        |
```

**Sequelize insert via NodeJS server
SQL statement:**

```
sequelize.query ("INSERT INTO ib_system_log (`login`, `action`, `action_type`) 
VALUES (:login, :action, :action_type)",{ replacements: { login: "test", action: "test", action_type: "test" }, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT })
```

**Result :**

```
| login |   action |    create_date_time  |   action_type |    
| test  |   test   |  2019-08-16 02:37:41 | test          |
```

Comment: I would prefer an answer to solve this globally as compared to changing each individual datetime

Comment: You should try to set "process.env.TZ" like this

`process.env.TZ = 'Europe/Amsterdam';`

in program that runs Sequelize. Of course, you must adapt timezone to your location.

Comment: Check also this post : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096692/change-sequelize-timezone)

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';  And, what TZ is the server set to?

Answer (score 0):

Set "process.env.TZ" in program that runs Sequelize

```
process.env.TZ = 'Europe/Amsterdam';
```

Of course, you must adapt timezone to your location. Check here for list of [timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)