# PostgreSQL date value is different when fetched from local databse & different when retured as an API call (locally & online)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, timezone

I have a PostgreSQL database locally & in Supabase.
When I run a query(below) in both, I get the exact response. Pics of the responses below

```
SELECT * FROM play_details
WHERE name = 'John Doe'
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = '2024'
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = '1'
```

I have a front end app (locally it is reading the local postgres and in deployment, it is reading the supabase database) in which i am making an API call to fetch the data but the date is different in them!!! I am running the exact query in both local & deployed version of the app. Why is this & how to fix this?

After some troubleshooting, I figured out that when converting the date to string with `toISOString()` ,the date is getting changed.

For example, on my machine, if I go to this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date and run the below code, the output is `"2023-12-31T18:30:00.000Z"` as you can see the date is **31st Dec 2023** instead of **1st Jan 2024**.

```
const date1 = new Date(2024, 0, 1).toISOString();
console.log(date1 );
```

I am guessing this has something to do with the issue I am having but unable to figure out why (I am not using `toISOString()` in my API call, just running the query & returning the response) & how to fix this issue so that it works well locally and after it is deployed.

**Update** Adding additional info as requested by Zegarek

The code to add the items into database is as below

```
import { getDB } from "./db";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const addConfirmation = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { player, confirmation, date } = req.body;
  const { db } = getDB();

  return await db
    .any(
      `INSERT INTO play_details (name,confirmation,hours_played,date)
      VALUES ('${player}', '${confirmation}','0','${date}')
      ON CONFLICT (name,date)
      DO UPDATE SET confirmation = '${confirmation}'
      RETURNING *`
    )
    .then((info) => {
      res.status(200).send(info);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    });
};

export default addConfirmation;
```

As you can see, I am requesting for the response after the data is added to the database & the strange thing is noticed is when this API call is made, the payload is correct but the response is already with the time stamp!!! Pics also added.

Payload

```
{"player":"mani1","confirmation":"yes","date":"2024-01-04"}
```

Response

```
 [
    {
        "id": 14165,
        "name": "mani1",
        "confirmation": "yes",
        "hours_played": "0.0",
        "date": "2024-01-03T18:30:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

[image: supabase]
[image: pgAdmin]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you get when you run a query `show timezone;` from the app in test vs in prod (local vs supabase)? My guess is something's mapping the db type `date` (no time of day) to js `date` (that includes time of day), applying timezone-aware shift. [See this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/NjfcwKPg)

Comment: When I run `show timezone`, on my local, i get `Asia/Calcutta` (I am in India, so makes sense), in prod, I get `UTC`. I think you are right that something is changing the applying timezone-aware shift

Comment: It would help if you attached the part of code showing how you write the values into the db table, how you read it from the there into js variables, and/or how you write/dump them elsewhere.

Comment: @Zegarek added info on how I am adding data into the table

Comment: Have you tried slapping a `Z` or `T00:00:00.000Z` to the end of the `date` in your payload? This should just instruct whatever this literal goes through, that it's already aligned to UTC and can be taken as-is. It's dirty and ideally, all elements of your system should be timezone-aware and not require you to deal with situations like this, especially not by injecting stuff with quiet assumptions that things are in UTC and will remain in UTC, but I'm sure it's already on someone's TODO list.

Comment: @Zegarek Thanks for the input. I will try it. Since the data in the table seems to be fine & just when extracting I am facing the problem, I changed the query for extracting as follows and it is working fine everywhere `SELECT id, name,confirmation,hours_played,date, CAST(date as CHAR(10)) FROM play_details`

Comment: You could also give [`to_char("date",'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MSZ')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) a chance, so that it's passed around in the preferable format: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Dqlu31tF). If you prefer the simple cast, stick to `::text`, [*don't use char(n)*](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29). Also, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096692/change-sequelize-timezone) might be relevant here: you could try to set up your config to switch your client to UTC for both read and write.